# Poles and zeros form of a transfer function

Tags: linear-systems, z-transform, transfer-function, digital-filters, poles-zeros

I know that a transfer function for a discrete-time LTI system can be written in the form

$$
H(z) = \frac{Y(z)}{X(z)} = \frac
{    \displaystyle\sum_{m=0}^M {b_m z^{-m}}}
{1 + \displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^N {a_n z^{-n}}}
$$

Now I am interested in the poles and zeros of this transfer function.
I have seen two different definitions:

$$
H(z) = \frac{Y(z)}{X(z)} = A\frac
{\displaystyle\prod_{k=1}^K (1 - \alpha_k z^{-1}) }
{\displaystyle\prod_{l=1}^L (1 - \beta_l  z^{-1}) } \tag{I}
$$

and

$$
H(z) = \frac{Y(z)}{X(z)} = B\frac
{\displaystyle\prod_{k=1}^K (z - \alpha_k) }
{\displaystyle\prod_{l=1}^L (z - \beta_l) } \tag{II}
$$

where $\alpha$ are zeros and $\beta$ are poles.

These definitions are not the same.
Thus, which of them is valid?
If both, what is the difference between them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The two expressions are generally not identical. In the special case $K=L$ they're equivalent, otherwise they differ by a (positive or negative) power of $z$:

$$\frac
{\displaystyle\prod_{k=1}^K (1 - \alpha_k z^{-1}) }
{\displaystyle\prod_{l=1}^L (1 - \beta_l  z^{-1}) }=\frac
{z^{-K}\displaystyle\prod_{k=1}^K (z - \alpha_k) }
{z^{-L}\displaystyle\prod_{l=1}^L (z - \beta_l) }=z^{L-K}\cdot\frac
{\displaystyle\prod_{k=1}^K (z - \alpha_k) }
{\displaystyle\prod_{l=1}^L (z - \beta_l) }$$

If $K\neq L$, there are poles or zeros at the origin.

Comment: Yes, yes. In my specific $K=L$ answer below I should have said "multiply $H_1(z)$ by $z^K/z^K$ (which is unity)." Thanks for the correct general answer Matt.

Answer (score 4):

@DaBler Ignoring the $A$ and $B$ factors, if you multiply $$
H_1(z) = \frac
{\displaystyle\prod_{k=1}^K (1 - \alpha_k z^{-1}) }
{\displaystyle\prod_{l=1}^L (1 - \beta_l  z^{-1}) }
$$ by the ratio $z/z$ (which is unity) you obtain $$
H_2(z) = \frac
{\displaystyle\prod_{k=1}^K (z - \alpha_k) }
{\displaystyle\prod_{l=1}^L (z - \beta_l) }
.$$ So the above $H_1(z) = H_2(z)$. I find the $H_2(z)$ form to be the easiest to use in finding the values of poles and zeros.

Comment: Just curious: how does this work at $z=0$ where $z/z$ is undefined?

Comment: I see. I assume I must multiply $z/z$ repeatedly according to $K$ or $L$ (whichever is greater). And in the end, I have multiple zeros or poles left at 0. Is that right?

Comment: That's only true if $K=L$; generally $H_1(z)\neq H_2(z)$.